# Determine who has created a Project in TFS2010

Tags: tfs

I need to find out who has created a project in TFS2010.
All permissions are generic and give no indication of who it was. There is no code checked in so I can't find a user name that way. 
The Project properties fields don't have a 'created by' section but this information must be saved somewhere? I've had a look through the database for a field but to no success.

So the question is where can I find the username of the person who created a Project in TFS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group 'Project Administrators' seems to be populated with the account name of the person who creates the project even if they're already in an AD group higher up. The username is explicitly added to this group.
I tried a couple of projects and this seems to be the case in them all.

This isn't completely reliable as you could add someone else and delete the initial Project Administrator. Looks to be the closest I'll get to the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine who originally created a Team Project, however... There will be files checked into source control. If you view history on the root node of the team project you will see a name.

In 2010 you always get a BuildTemplates folder created by the user who created the team project.

Answer (score -2):

If the project includes GUID, you can use it to identify the MAC address of network card of the workstation where it is generated. Part of any GUID (48bits) is MAC address.